# Python send/ recv binary data

Tags: python, sockets, networking

I a trying to send and receive binary data in python(v3). The way I am attempting to do it is at the client end, I manually create a string of bytes and then send it through a socket to the server. On the server side, I receive the data and manually access individual bits to resolve the message.

This is how the client looks:

```
remoteIP = "164.107.112.72"
remotePort = 34562
remoteStruct = remoteIP.split('.', 4)
remoteIPBytes = ((int)(remoteStruct[0])).to_bytes(1, byteorder='little') + ((int)(remoteStruct[1])).to_bytes(1, byteorder='little') + ((int)(remoteStruct[2])).to_bytes(1, byteorder='little') + ((int)(remoteStruct[3])).to_bytes(1, byteorder='little')

headerStruct = remoteIPBytes + remotePort.to_bytes(2, byteorder='little')
sequenceNum = 0
size = #filesize

data = headerStruct + sequenceNum.to_bytes(1, byteorder='little') + (1).to_bytes(1,byteorder='little') + size.to_bytes(4, byteorder='little')
#data is then sent to server
```

this is how the server handles the data:

```
serversock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)   # UDP Datagram
host = '164.107.112.70'
serversock.bind((host, localPort))

seqNum = 0

#get size
size = 0
var = serversock.recvfrom(12)
seqNum = int.from_bytes((str(var))[6], byteorder='little')
```

In that last line of code, I get an error saying that (str(var)) is being treated as a unicode string rather than a binary one. However, if I don't cast as a string, I get an access out of bounds error.

Can someone explain to me what the correct way to send and receive binary data in python is? I have tried using struct.pack and unpack before/after sending data, but I always get errors during the unpacking, even though the format strings are identical

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> `(int)(remoteStruct[0])`

This looks a lot like some C code.  Python doesn't have type casts like C.

`int` refers to an object.  The way you use it is by calling it - like it's a function.

Instead write something like `int(remoteStruct[0])`.  What you wrote works because the extra parenthesis are totally redundant and don't change the meaning.  This isn't just a syntactic difference, though.  It's a basic difference in the type systems of the two languages.

This has nothing to do with your question, though.

```
IPBytes = ((int)(remoteStruct[0])).to_bytes(1, byteorder='little') + ((int)(remoteStruct[1])).to_bytes(1, byteorder='little') + ((int)(remoteStruct[2])).to_bytes(1, byteorder='little') + ((int)(remoteStruct[3])).to_bytes(1, byteorder='little')
```

This is an *incredibly* verbose way to pack an IPv4 address into four bytes.  Try this instead:

```
import socket
print socket.inet_pton(socket.AF_INET, "1.2.3.4")
```

Though this is also not directly related to your question.

The source of your `IndexError` problem (I'm guessing that's the exception you encounter, you said "access out of bounds error" which isn't something that actually exists in Python's built-in types - don't paraphrase errors, quote them verbatim) is very likely somewhere in the vicinity of:

```
var = serversock.recvfrom(12)
```

Notice the return value of [recvfrom](http://docs.python.org/3/library/socket.html#socket.socket.recvfrom): *The return value is a pair (bytes, address)*.

If you try to index into this object at `6` then you'll definitely get an `IndexError` raised, yes.

Using `str` to get a unicode string representation of this pair won't really help though - although it might prevent the indexing operation from failing because the resulting unicode string will probably be long enough. :)  You'll be getting garbage, though.

Instead, try indexing into the bytes that you read instead:

```
data, addr = serversock.recvfrom(12)

if len(data) > 6:
    seqNum = ord(data[6])
```

Notice you really do need to be careful about length checking here.  Just because you passed `12` to `recvfrom` doesn't mean it returns 12 bytes.  It means it returns *up to* 12 bytes.  You don't want your program to explode with an unhandled exception the first time someone sends you a short datagram.